# MySQL (version lower than 8.0) : SELECT WHERE Multiple column and group by max level

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mariadb-10.1

I have 2 tables in my database.

1. table of employees in my department. This table is stored centrally. Which I have no right to manage in this table

| emp_id | name | job postion | dept_1 | dept_2 | dept_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000010 | emp1 name1 | Director | CEO | Human resource |  |
| 000012 | emp2 name2 | employee | CEO | Human resource |  |
| 000013 | emp2 name2 | Director | CEO | Human resource | Recruitment |
| 000014 | emp2 name2 | employee | CEO | Human resource | Recruitment |
| 000015 | emp2 name2 | employee | CEO | Human resource | Recruitment |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |  |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |  |
| 000200 | emp2 name2 | Head Director | CEO |  |  |

2. Department table. It's a table that I have created to show my department.

| dept_id | dept_level | dept_name | dept_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | CEO | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Human Resource | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | Recruitment | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | Training | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | Sale | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | Sale planning | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | Sale marketing | 7 |

I want to know Which department's employees are under?

I tried using the command :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER table2 ON (table2.dept_name = table1.dept_1 OR table2.dept_name = table1.dept_2 OR table2.dept_name = table1.dept_3)
```

But it's not the answer I want.

I want

| emp_id | name | job postion | dept_level | dept_name | dept_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000010 | emp1 name1 | Director | 2 | Human Resource | 2 |
| 000012 | emp2 name2 | employee | 2 | Human Resource | 2 |
| 000013 | emp2 name2 | Director | 3 | Recruitment | 3 |
| 000200 | emp2 name2 | Head Director | 1 | CEO | 1 |

What should I do?

P.S. Sorry my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, MAX(d.dept_level) OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id) maxlevel
              FROM employees e
              JOIN department d ON d.dept_name IN (e.dept_1, e.dept_2, e.dept_3) )
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE dept_level = maxlevel
ORDER BY emp_id
```

For MySQL 5.7 / MariaDB 10.1 use

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees e
JOIN department d ON d.dept_name IN (e.dept_1, e.dept_2, e.dept_3)
JOIN ( SELECT e.emp_id,
              MAX(d.dept_level) maxlevel
       FROM employees e
       JOIN department d ON d.dept_name IN (e.dept_1, e.dept_2, e.dept_3)
       GROUP BY e.emp_id ) ed USING (emp_id)
WHERE d.dept_level = ed.maxlevel
ORDER BY emp_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=45a26cbd6cd337f87e7e4e4663141133)

Comment: I have even more problems. mysql does not support the command of WITH ..... AS and OVER (PARTITION BY ....... )   Are there any alternatives to suggest?

Comment: @HackerDewdie *mysql does not support the command of WITH ..... AS and OVER (PARTITION BY ....... )* Fiddle doesn't agree with you - all these constructions works successfully, and used DBMS is exactly MySQL.

Comment: Sorry I can't write clearly.I mean the database I am using. A version lower than 8.0.  Another I just know that on this day that The database currently used is mariaDB but not mysql (I've always understood that I am using mysql) .If to compare versions, I am using mariaDB version 10.1.38 which is expected to be equivalent to mysql version 5.7.

Comment: @HackerDewdie Add this into the question text with bold font! and adjust question tags. Next time do this firstly.

Comment: Sorry for late reply I have applied to the Employees table again because I have another subquery. Now I need to JOIN many more tables. No wonder why the new version must have WITH ..... AS and OVER (PARTITION BY .......)

Comment: @HackerDewdie New question needs in new topic creation.